# Ignore $in if empty array is provided

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model:

```
export type IMangaModel = Document & {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  demographic: Array<string>;
  genre: Array<string>;
  tags: Array<string>;
  related: Array<IMangaModel>;
  cover_image: {
    extraLarge: string | null;
    large: string | null;
    medium: string | null;
  };
  banner: string | null;
  al_id: number;
  al_url: string;
  likes: Array<IUserModel['_id']>;
};
```

Note: interface matches the model exactly but i pasted this as its much shorter.

I am using the following data to filter through this collection:

```
includeFilters: {
    genres: Array<string>;
    tags: Array<string>;
    demographics: Array<string>;
  };
  excludeFilters: {
    genres: Array<string>;
    tags: Array<string>;
    demographics: Array<string>;
  };
```

What i want to achieve is to find every document and check if the corresponding array has at least one of the values from the array i sent via includeFilters. While it has none of the values sent via excludeFilters.

To do this i used the following query:

```js
const results = await this._manga
      .find(
        {
          tags: {
            $elemMatch: {
              $in: data.includeFilters.tags,
              $nin: data.excludeFilters.tags,
            },
          },
          genre: {
            $elemMatch: {
              $in: data.includeFilters.genres,
              $nin: data.excludeFilters.genres,
            },
          },
          demographic: {
            $elemMatch: {
              $in: data.includeFilters.demographics,
              $nin: data.excludeFilters.demographics,
            },
          },
        },
        { al_id: 1 }
      );
```

This seems to works fine *as long* as all of the arrays in includeFilters array have at least one value. But if an empty array is provided then no matches are found with $in, from what i understand $in requires at least one value to be present, but as nothing is provided then nothing is found. On the other hand, **$nin** works fine (at least i'd like to think so) because its not trying to exclude any values.

What i would like to achieve is that if an empty array is provided to $in then it outright just skips through that filter and doesnt look at it. When doing this in mysql if an empty array is provided then its ignored and every record is returned as a result. This is what i want with mongodb.

What i have tried till now are a couple of things.

First i tried to just add every possible value to array's that are empty, this did not work for one reason, not all documents have the tags,genres and demographic data. So in the end nearly 90% of all documents are not included in the result.

Second thing i tried was to enable the **ignoreUndefined** option in the connection options. And then when creating the query check if the length is 0, if it is, pass undefined to **$in**. This did not work.

Third thing i tried was going through every possible scenario where some array is empty, this was bad for obvious reasons so i scratched it.

Fourth thing i tried was to make a function to build a dynamic query of sorts, this also became very messy because of the amount of possibilities.

Fifth and last thing  i tried was using **$or** with the idea that the empty results would somehow be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work better with TypeScript you could use Nenad's approach with ES6 methods

```js
const filters = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(body).flatMap(([filterType, filters]) =>
    Object.entries(filters)
      .filter(([, values]) => values.length)
      .map(([key, value]) =>
        filterType === "includeFilters"
          ? [key, { $elemMatch: { $in: [...value] } }]
          : [key, { $elemMatch: { $nin: [...value] } }]
      )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to just dynamically create the whole filter. It will also simplify your query. You can do it like this:

```
let elem_match = {
  tags: {},
  genres: {},
  demographics: {}
}

for (let key in data.includeFilters){
  if(data.includeFilters[key].length) elem_match[key]["$in"] = data.includeFilters[key];
}

for (let key in data.excludeFilters){
  if(data.excludeFilters[key].length) elem_match[key]["$nin"] = data.excludeFilters[key];
}

let filter = {};
for (let key in elem_match){
  if(Object.keys(elem_match[key]).length !== 0) filter[key] = { $elemMatch: elem_match[key]}
}

const results = await this._manga.find(filter, { al_id: 1 });
```

Here is a snippet for testing:

```js
let includeFilters = {
  genres: ['1', '2'],
  tags: ['1', '2'],
  demographics: ['1', '2']
};

let excludeFilters = {
  genres: ['1', '2'],
  tags: ['1', '2'],
  demographics: ['1', '2']
};

let elem_match = {
    tags: {},
  genres: {},
  demographics: {}
}

for (let key in includeFilters) {
    if(includeFilters[key].length) elem_match[key]["$in"] = includeFilters[key];
}

for (let key in excludeFilters) {
    if(excludeFilters[key].length) elem_match[key]["$nin"] = excludeFilters[key];
}

let filter = {};
for (let key in elem_match) {
    if(Object.keys(elem_match[key]).length !== 0) filter[key] = { $elemMatch: elem_match[key]}
}

console.log('Filter: ', filter)
```

Comment: This will not work as it is, it needs a lot more edge cases. As i said there isnt just one possibility of one array not provided. If i were to expand this i would come to the same result of hard coding the entire query and it would come down to a few dozen lines just for this one query

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you check it? This will dynamically create query object needed, so you can cover more use cases really easily. This should work if you provide both arrays, only one, or none.

Comment: It doesnt work, it only works when i provide at least one element in every array. I think its because $elemMatch is provided regardless if array is passed or not. Maybe that creates an issue?

Comment: Yup, you are probably right. I refactored code so now it the whole filter will be created dynamically and not just the `match_elem` objects. Can you try it now?

Comment: This seems to work now i think. Will have to manually go through some data and check if its precise. But this just comes down to what i wanted to avoid in the end. Which is hard coding. Not to mention that typescript is just screaming at me because of all the implicit any types. Is there really no other way to do this?

Comment: Let me know if it worked when you test it. But now you don't need to do anything. You should just create `includeFilters` and `excludeFilters` and send it to the endpoint. The query filter will be created accordingly. Also if you are using Typescript with strict mode, you can just explicitly add type `any`. Also, consider approving and upvoting my answer if it will work for you.